# Where can I find updated source code for Jorge Acetozi book "Continuous Delivery for Java Apps: Kubernetes and Jenkins in Practice"

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jenkins, kubernetes, java-11

I just started reading the Jorge Acetozi book "Continuous Delivery for Java Apps: Kubernetes and Jenkins in Practice".
For the code examples I use the source code in his github repository:
https://github.com/jorgeacetozi

Unfortunately this code doesn't work for Java 11 and uses old Spring Boot 1.5 version
Also Jenkins, Selenium, Kubernetes and Vagrant tools, described in the book, use very old versions.

Has anyone finished this book lately, could you please, provide the updated source code for this book?

Unfortunately, the old source code, prevents me from learning further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to finish this book, but did a lot of changes to the source code:

1. https://github.com/skyglass/notepad - updated source code for Notepad Spring Boot application.

- Spring Boot has been updated to version 2.4.2.
- I had to make lots of changes to the front-end code, to make styles displayed correctly with the latest version of Thymeleaf library.
- Also did some other changes, related to update from Java8 to Java11.
- All maven dependencies have been updated to the latest versions

2. https://github.com/skyglass/jenkins-kubernetes-cd - This repository corresponds to Jorge Acetozi's "ebook-continuous-delivery-with-kubernetes-and-jenkins" repository.

- "docker-images" folder contain "jenkins", "kubectl" and "maven-jdk11-git" docker image files, which are used by Jenkins pipelines
- Kubernetes yaml files have been updated to the latest version of Kubernetes
- Unfortunately, I couldn't manage to make acceptance tests working for "Firefox" browser, with the latest "Selenium Grid" docker images. Therefore, acceptance-tests pipeline code only contains tests with "Chrome" browser
- All Jenkins files have been updated to use the latest docker images, or custom docker images, published by me in Skyglass Docker Hub. Feel free to publish them in your own docker hub, using docker files from "docker-images" folder.
- "docker-images" folder contains custom docker image to run Jenkins. I recommend using this image to run Jenkins on your computer. It uses the latest version of jenkins for jdk11 and all needed plugins with the latest versions

3. https://github.com/skyglass/notepad-performance-tests - the performance tests have been updated for the latest versions of Scala, SBT and Gatling.
4. https://tferdinand.net/en/create-a-local-kubernetes-cluster-with-vagrant/
   https://www.exxactcorp.com/blog/HPC/building-a-kubernetes-cluster-using-vagrant

- These articles will help you to install Kubernetes Cluster locally, with Vagrant and VirtualBox.

Of course, I also used lot of other online resources. StackOverflow helped me a lot. :)

Have fun reading this book, hope these examples help you get the best learning experience.

Thank you, Jorge Acetozi, for this wonderful book!

Comment: Have you tried JX Jenkins X (Golang version with tekton pipelines)? I recommend you a viktor farcic's devops toolkit series